# автоматизация платежей android

Tags: java, android, webmoney

планируем доску обьявлений для не очень большего города.
с реализацией то справляемся хотя и мы начинающие.
Но с монетизацией затрудняемся.
Первый вопрос как можно монетизировать?
Второй вопрос как можно автоматизировать платежи VIP обьявлений?
Всем кто обратит внимание спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Вопрос слишком общий.Но отвечу в целом .

- (Монетизация)Для начала если есть аудитория то можно добавить за счет
  введения платных услуг, показа рекламы, размещения ссылок и т.п
- -(Автоматизировать)Ясный пень это делать в ручную вы не будете ,думаю нужен сервак где будет сервис которуму идет запрос на обьявление и по
  определенным критериям он сам знает какой у него приоритет в показе
  .Насамом деле это очень легко.